# invalid user-defined conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const string& {aka const std::basic_string<char>&}’ [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, string, types, type-conversion

I'm a student, my program is divided in 3 parts, but the last part is where i'm getting troubles, and i cannot find a way to resolve it, it shows me:

> invalid user-defined conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const string& {aka
>   const std::basic_string&}’ [-fpermissive] 
>    while(!st.empty() && st.top() != '(' &&
>   hasHigherPrecedence(st.top(),expr[i])){

My code:

```
string StacksAndQueues::convertInfixToPostfix(const string &expr) {
stack<char> st;
int n = expr.length();
string res = "";

for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
    if(expr[i] == '0' || expr[i] == '1' || expr[i] == '2' || expr[i] == '3' || expr[i] == '4' || expr[i] == '5' || expr[i] == '6' || 
    expr[i] == '7' || expr[i] == '8' || expr[i] == '9'){
        res = res + expr[i];
    }else if(expr[i] == '+' || expr[i] == '-' || expr[i] == '*' || expr[i] == '/'){
        while(!st.empty() && st.top() != '(' && hasHigherPrecedence(st.top(),expr[i])){
            res = res + st.top();
            st.pop();
        }
        st.push(expr[i]);
    }
    else if (expr[i] == '(') 
    {
        st.push(expr[i]);
    }

    else if(expr[i] == ')') 
    {
        while(!st.empty() && st.top() !=  '(') {
            res = res + st.top();
            st.pop();
        }
        st.pop();
    }
}
while(!st.empty()) {
    res = res + st.top();
    st.pop();
}
return res;
```

}

```
bool StacksAndQueues::hasHigherPrecedence(const string &stackTop, const string &op) {
return !((stackTop == string("+") || stackTop == string("-")) &&
         (op == string("*")       || op == string("/")));
```

}

Comment: `st.top()` is a char, but you give it as first argument to a function expecting string

Comment: And `std::string` doesn't have a conversion constructor that accepts only a single `char` as input, but it can be passed to one of the other constructors, eg: `hasHigherPrecedence(string(1,st.top()), ...)` or `hasHigherPrecedence(string(&st.top(), 1), ...)`